# Questions about ArangoLocalStorage deployment

Tags: arangodb

With :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/ArangoDBDeployment# cat arangoDeployment.yaml 
apiVersion: "database.arangodb.com/v1"
kind: "ArangoDeployment"
metadata:
  name: "cluster"
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  mode: Cluster
  agents:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        communicationMethod: ip
        image: 1.2.33
        storageClassName: my-local-ssd
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
  dbservers:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        communicationMethod: ip
        strategy:
          type: Recreate
        image: 1.2.33
        storageClassName: my-local-ssd
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
        communicationMethod: headless-dns

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl apply -f ./ArangoDBDeployment/arangoDeployment.yaml 
arangodeployment.database.arangodb.com/cluster configured
```

And this DB Servers, it seems working fine:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dANK6OZ8iLa7eqUQSoU7vqYVqTvISM80/view?usp=sharing

Now I would like to add `ArangoLocalStorage` : https://docs.arangodb.com/stable/deploy/deployment/kubernetes/storage-resource/

And about this further step, I would like to ask you few questions :

***Question 1*** :  It is not clear to me if

**Option A**: I can add :

```
kind: "ArangoLocalStorage"
metadata:
  name: "example-arangodb-storage"
spec:
  storageClass:
    name: my-local-ssd
  localPath:
  - /mnt/big-ssd-disk
```

to the already present  'ArangoDeployment` operator :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/ArangoDBDeployment# ls -lah
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 17 16:31 .
drwx------ 7 root root 4.0K Oct 17 16:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  793 Oct 17 16:30 arangoDeployment.yaml

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/ArangoDBDeployment# cat arangoDeployment.yaml 
apiVersion: "database.arangodb.com/v1"
kind: "ArangoDeployment"
metadata:
  name: "cluster"
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  mode: Cluster
  agents:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        communicationMethod: ip
        image: 1.2.33
        storageClassName: my-local-ssd
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
  dbservers:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        communicationMethod: ip
        strategy:
          type: Recreate
        image: 1.2.33
        storageClassName: my-local-ssd
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
        communicationMethod: headless-dns
```

or,

**Option B** : if I have to apply a new operator `ArangoLocalStorage.yaml` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/ArangoDBDeployment# ls -lah
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct 17 16:52 .
drwx------ 7 root root 4.0K Oct 17 16:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  793 Oct 17 16:30 arangoDeployment.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  195 Oct 17 16:52 arangoLocalStorage.yaml

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/ArangoDBDeployment# cat arangoLocalStorage.yaml 
apiVersion: "storage.arangodb.com/v1alpha"
kind: "ArangoLocalStorage"
metadata:
  name: "example-arangodb-storage"
spec:
  storageClass:
    name: my-local-ssd
  localPath:
  - /mnt/big-ssd-disk
```

Question 2 :  is `localPath` compulsory ? And it has to be the same for all nodes of the cluster ?